# Use xkb to change Caps Lock to Alt+Tab

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, remapping, xkb

I'm trying to find a way to use xkb settings to change the behavior of my Caps Lock key (when no modifier keys are pressed) and remap it to to the Alt+Tab key combination instead.

I am also open to using xmodmap or some other tool, instead of xkb.

However, I haven't been able to find out the proper way to remap the Caps Lock key to Alt+Tab, using either tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do also some tuning with `xkb` and I can figure out a workaround.
You can map a multimedia shortcut to the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>

```
key <CAPS> { [ XF86ApplicationRight ] };
```

You have a [pretty big list](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/XF86_keyboard_symbols) of supported shortcuts, just pick one..

Then you can map the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to perform ***switching*** application (ie. switching to next opened windows in one press without displaying an overlay)
It also works with regular ***cycling windows*** however it seems to only toggle the last windows.

I think that cycling windows needs a shortcut that have a modifier key in order to keep the list of opened windows (the thumbnails overlay) and then to allow cycling to the desired window.

But this is a workaround that actually works.  In most distro the shortcut settings for this is under ***Windows Manager*** settings.